# How can I create a plot with data located in one column of a table with R?

Tags: r, csv, shiny, survey, summarize

I would like to extract information from a csv table that contains survey answers. The goal is to create informal graphs for my shiny app to show the result of the survey.

To simplify the process I want to create the plots in a standard R file first. As the answers for one question are all in the same column, I think that I need to separate the different answers first before making a plot.

This is how the imported table looks:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yfdMF0gZQKFbMFOChN8lEXzl1KxLsGBp/view?usp=sharing

As first graph I'd like to create a pie chart with the information from the column with the question "how did you travel to the event?". The answers are by car, by bicycle, by train/bus, by motorcycle, by feet or by bus.

With summary(u18) I found out, that in column "Verkehrsmittel" (=means of transportation) can be found following count of answers:

Verkehrsmittel

Auto                       : 15 (= car)

Fahrrad                    : 17 (= bicycle)

Öffentliche Verkehrsmittel :252 (= train/bus)

Zu Fuss                    :  6 (= by feet)

Reisebus                   :  1 (= bus)

Motorrad                   :  1 (= motorcycle)

with that information I'd like to create a plot looking like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZhKhb3gADI1-CI_qIgaYlE1A2swZYcKR/view?usp=sharing

How do I have to prepare the data to be able to perform plots like this?
There are empty cells as well (N/A) how can I handle that?

I tried to transform data according to the instruction on the cheat sheet of data.table package and the summary function of dplyr package but I couldn't manage to write a correct syntax as I found no similar example.

My code so far (with a trial wrong pie plot that looks psychedelic):

```
# -----------------------------------------------------
# Tabellen verarbeiten für SA2
# -----------------------------------------------------

# Libraries
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(plotrix)

# Verzeichnis setzen
setwd("C:/Users/julie/Desktop/R/tables")

# csv einlesen
u18 = read.csv("Umfrage2018.csv", sep=";", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

# Anzeigen 
#View(u18)

# gleiche Antworten zusammenfassen
#summary(u18,"Verkehrsmittel")

# Datentyp anzeigen
#str(u18)

# Variablen
anreise = u18$Verkehrsmittel

# Plot
pie.anreise <- c(anreise)
# Beschriftung der Stücke
names(pie.anreise) <- c("Auto","Fahrrad","Motorrad","ÖV", "Reisebus", "zu Fuss")
# Befehl für Plot, Farben der Stücke
pie(pie.anreise,col = c("green4","green2","blue", "yellow","orange","red"))
# Beschriftungen cex.xy = Schriftgrösse, font.xy = Schriftart: 1 = normal, 2 = fett, 3 = kursiv
title(main = "Anreise 2018", cex.main = 1.8, font.main = 1)
title(xlab = "(SOLA Stafette)", cex.lab = 0.8, font.lab = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people will tell you that pie charts are bad, which is why all these packages will annoyingly keep you from making them (I think it's OK, people intuitively understand things add up to 100% with pie charts).

But if you want to do it, you can use the `ggplot2` library and the `coord_polar()` function:

```
library(ggplot2)

your_data <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                        transp = c('bus','bus','car','car','bus'))

ggplot(your_data) + aes(x = factor(1), fill = transp) +
  geom_bar() + coord_polar(theta = 'y')
```